# plotting a function defined by parametric integral

Tags: integral, wxmaxima

I am going to plot2d the function f(x) which is defined by a parametric integral

```
load("c:/work3/nint.mac");
g(x,y):=x*y;
f(x):=nint(g(x,t),t,1,100);
wxplot2d(f(x),['x,0,10]);
```

> plot2d: expression evaluates to non-numeric value everywhere in
>   plotting range.

Comment: Hi Gabor, welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you elaborate and give us more details about your question?

Comment: It is probably important to know what's the definition of `nint`.

Comment: Without knowing more about it, my first guess is that you need to postpone evaluation of `nint` until `x` has some definite value. Perhaps you can try `wxplot2d(f, [x, 0, 10])` or `wxplot('(f(x)), [x, 0, 10])` or perhaps `wxplot('f(x), [x, 0, 10])`.

Comment: nint is explained in the following page: https://web.csulb.edu/~woollett/nint.mac